# New M1 Macbook Pro, warranty expired

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty, apple-silicon

I bought a new MacBook Pro with an M1 chip today from a third-party supplier. After all of the setup, I found that its warranty was listed as expired.

This model released earlier this year and is definitely not over 1 year old. I used Geekbench to test it and all marks looks good.

Does anyone has any idea on what I could do?

Comment: Have you verified the expired warranty with Apple?

Comment: The seller refuse to provide recipes for his purchase so Apple won’t help me to verify the warranty dates

Comment: No receipt?!?!? That should throw red flags! Try this site: https://checkcoverage.apple.com/

Comment: Yeah, it’s truly expired. And I didn’t get what cause it

Comment: Could it be that this is a refurbished unit? Those generally come with a 90 day warranty only. Or it could perhaps be some kind of replacement unit from Apple on a warranty case, so that this unit itself is without warranty?

Comment: @jksoegaard I bought an Apple refurb laptop and it came with a 1 year warranty, but that was the Apple refurb system not third party. Perhaps the lesson is to buy from Apple...

Comment: Sounds like you need to report the seller to someone - tax authorities, trading standards, police. Or at least threaten to do so if they don't give you a refund.

Answer (score 4):

A call to Apple support or web interaction would let you provide purchase information to correct an accounting error on the registration. This has been true for a decade and isn’t specific to the M1 Mac.

To get to this, open the “About this Mac” item from the Apple menu or use this handy web site - https://support.apple.com/repair-products

[image]

Select the service tab and then the check my coverage status. Apple doesn’t need you to provide anything but a receipt that you obtained from your seller in most cases.

Also keep in mind, sales into some countries mean you have to provide proof of purchase or seek support first from the person you bought the product or a company in the region of first sale instead of Apple directly.

- https://www.apple.com/legal/
- https://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/statutoryrights.html

Hopefully you didn’t buy a Mac that didn’t even finish manufacturing by Apple or was stolen directly from Apple. I clearly can’t know what information an Apple agent would find in their research to decline coverage. There are so many edge cases you may not have considered that someone at Apple not only has faced multiple times, but had to write a playbook for how to handle these rare cases so they’re being consistent and not “shooting from the hip” call by call. One might be if you had a Mac they used in store for a display and it was stolen during a robbery. I could understand the call asking for support on those Macs to be a short one and read from a script that is designed to bring the call to a quick conclusion.

Comment: I think in the comments, it was mentioned that the seller didn't provide a receipt, so it would be difficult to prove eligibility. However, I'd speak to Apple still, because clearly an M1 Mac is still within the first year of it being sold and should have warranty. Also I suggest looking at your country's statutory warranty which may provide additional coverage even after the first year of complementary Apple Care warranty has expired.

Comment: @AVelj as I said, Apple will honor any written proof generally when it aligns with what they know based on manufacture. This whole thread is suspect since no country offers consumer protection on goods without a paper trail. In fact, consumer protection depends on organizations operating to pay taxes and offer goods according to legal sales. This is clearly a contrived situation (or facts are not all being reported) but my experience is Apple isn’t out to penalize people if they made a buying mistake. Dealing in stolen goods or even gray market can be risky and you end up with no support.

Comment: I gave them a call last night, they said this machine is not eligible for any warranty. They also said they cannot tell me the reason, which is so wired.

Comment: Bummer @LinCui only case I could theorize is if the serial number is bogus or if they are under court order / policy to not report a theft.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying @bmike, but surely consumer law rights would still apply if it's clearly known that an M1 mac has only been out for less than a year?

Comment: No @AVelj - what if this was a developer kit or stolen before Apple could sell it the first time or a prototype? That would be like forcing Apple to support a Dell or even a knock off that someone else assembled and sold as legit. Something could be so wrong with the serial number  or how ihis one Mac became “up for third party sale” that no one that knew the particulars Apple and Lin experienced would expect support to be granted. Common law establishes responsibilities on both sides of the market and is highly dependent on specific facts about  Lin”s specific transaction.